# I am trying something with javascript closure

Tags: javascript

I got 2 functions:

```
var number1 = 9
var number2 = 17;

//Get Percent of a the number1
function getPercent(x, y) {
    return x * 100 / y;
}
var percentOfNumber1 = getPercent(number1, number2);

//Get rid of remainder 
function getRemain(t) {
    var remainder = t % 2;
    t = t - remainder;
    return t;
}
alert(getRemain(percentOfNumber1));
```

That works..but I want to close the getRemain function in the first function.

so What I did and I dont' get result with:

```
function getPercent(x, y) {
    return x * 100 / y;

    function getRemain(t) {
        var remainder = t % 2;
        t = t - remainder;
        return t;
    }
    var numberClear = getRemain(result);
}
var result = getPercent(number1, number2);
alert(numberClear);
```

Can anyone explain the wrong approach to this? 
"this is the first time I try closures I read couple of good explanations but didin't get the calling functions part really good I guess.."
Thnx.

Comment: If you indent your code you will see it makes no sense.

Comment: that comment doesn't make sense to me either!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare `numberClear` outside if you want to access it outside:

```
var numberClear;

function getPercent(x, y) {
    function getRemain(t) {
        return t - t % 2;
    }
    var result = x * 100 / y;
    numberClear = getRemain(result);
    return result;
}

var result = getPercent(number1, number2);
alert(numberClear);
```

Comment: You should never rely on globals though.

Comment: @Matteo Tassinari: where do you see any *globals* in this code?

Comment: @zerkms I was referring to the first line.

Comment: @Matteo Tassinari: and it's not a global variable

Comment: Since there is no other indication, I would assume that code is in the global scope, so it is.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari If it was global scope, I would have use `window` to make it clear it is global. But of course, the code can run in global scope too if asker desires that.

Comment: @Matteo Tassinari: "I would assume that code is in the global scope" --- you're making too much assumptions. Why don't you assume that code is even in a `.js` file then?

Comment: @user2045937 Glad to to hear it works as you want. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: @zerkms You're assuming as much as I am, else how could you say it was not global scope?

Comment: @Matteo Tassinari: I'm not making any assumptions - it's just *a variable*. That's it

Answer (score 1):

Why not this?

Return both the values at once

```
function getPercentage(a, b){
   function getRemain(t)
    {
        var remainder = t % 2;
        t = t - remainder;
        return t; 
    }
   return {
      percentage: a / b * 100,
      remain: getRemain(a / b * 100)
   }
};

var result = getPercentage(9, 17);
alert(result.percentage);
alert(result.remain);
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply didn't return the result properly:

```
function getPercent(x,y)
{
    function getRemain(t)
    {
        var remainder = t % 2;
        t = t - remainder;
        return t; 
    }
    return getRemain(x * 100 / y); // <-- return what getRemain() gives you!
}

var result = getPercent(number1, number2);
```

Comment: It might be helpful to explain that there is no closures in this code as well

Comment: If there is no closure in this code then I understood closures totally wrong..In stead of writing comment to everyone why don't you explain what I am trying to do and why It does't work..

Comment: A closure is a function that isn't accessible in the global scope. Kinda

Comment: @FabianCook: "A closure is a function that isn't accessible in the global scope" --- not even close. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: @FabianCook: you don't understand. It has **NOTHING** to do with scope or visibility. Closure is a context + a function. That simple.

Comment: "In short, variables from the parent function of the closure remain bound from the parent's scope."

Comment: They have everything to do with scope

Comment: @FabianCook: yep. Your quote talks about **variables** not about functions. Please read that link carefully before you decide to continue this pointless discussion. Thank you.

Comment: The variables in the scope of the parent are also bound to the closure.

Comment: @FabianCook: yes they are. Now please read the whole discussion from the beginning. A hint: "A closure is a function that isn't accessible in the global scope" --- is totally wrong.

Comment: Now read the kinda part, I know they can be accessible, and usually are. Now explain why there are no closures in this?

Comment: @FabianCook: because to be a closure - a function need to refer to free variables. Have you read the **first line** of the link I gave?

Comment: Our understanding is different. Meh. I know what they are. Thats good enough for me

Comment: @FabianCook: there is no "my" or "your" understanding. It is an official term with a single meaning. Your understanding doesn't match it (surprisingly you start misunderstanding it on a very first line lol). Whatever, I don't care.

Comment: This is the official guide, please tell me where it says what a closure is. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/

Comment: @Niko: technically `getRemain` doesn't refer to them.

Comment: When tends to be something part of getRemain

Comment: @FabianCook: the scope doesn't refer to anything, scope just hold references to **its** values.

Comment: Guys, please read: 1. the link to the MDN I gave in the beginning 2. http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/es5-chapter-3-2-lexical-environments-ecmascript-implementation/ before you continue wasting your and my time. Thank you.

Comment: http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-6-closures/ 

"we see that all functions in ECMAScript are closures"

Comment: @FabianCook: well, I can accept that technically they are because of *ECMAScript implementation*. But still, it's a common CS term, not a js specific one. (and still, it has nothing to do with your interpretation).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to access a variable declared inside a function from outside it.

You could try this:

```
var getPercent = (function() {
  function getRemain(t)
  {
    var remainder = t % 2;
    t = t - remainder;
    return t;
  }

  return function (x,y)
  {
    var percent = x * 100 / y;
    return {
      percent: percent,
      remainder: getRemain(percent)
    };     
  }
})();
```

In this way the `getRemain` function is not accessible and the `getPercent` function will return both the percent and remainder values.

Comment: Why do you give a name for function expression?

Comment: In this case it has no practical utility, but I like it more this way.

Comment: And `window.getPercent` is a terrible advice - to pollute a global scope without a real reason. You might have returned an anonymous function from your IIFE instead

Comment: @zerkms How would you access the function from outside the closure instead?

Comment: 1. There are no any closures in your code, only named and anonymous functions 2. I would just return it

Comment: As of point 2, you'd have to do something like `var getPercent = (function() { ... })();` which is just about the same of what I did if such var is in the global scope.

Comment: "**if** such var is in the global scope"

Comment: Edited so it just returns the `getPercent` function.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var numberClear;

    function getPercent(x, y) {
        var percentange = x * 100 / y;
        numberClear = getRemain(result); // set your numberClear Variable here
        return percentange;
    }

     function getRemain(t) {
            return t - t % 2;
        }

    var result = getPercent(number1, number2);
    alert(numberClear);
```